# Drupal Commerce does not work correctly with attributes

Tags: commerce

I have installed [Drupal Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) and I am attempting to migrate a **wig store** from an old version of Zen Cart that has been abandoned for years.

All I have seen so far is that to load attributes you have to create different products that will be shown as 1 product.

But this is not how I can migrate this store: *first, I can only create one product with the color shown, that is how manufacturer provides info.*

For an example of what I need to migrate: http://ladywig.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=17_43_44&products_id=175

I need to load only certain images and names that apply to a certain product, from a much larger vocabulary of names and images.

Customer can only select one color attribute per product. Nobody in Commerce seems to have a clue about how to do this, somebody will come up with the brilliant idea to pay for a custom module, but this does not make sense to me because I could rebuild that site with a newer version of Zencart and obtain the functionality I need for free.

So can similar functionality be achieved with Commerce, or with the addition of some contributed module?

Comment: I don't get you. You just create different Commerce products, one for each variation of the Store Product. Then you create a product display that has an multi-value entity reference field set to each of the Commerce products you created. Shoppers interact with this product display. You set the attribute (on the Commerce product) to 'Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms.' and voila. Manual capturing products will kill you, so you will have to use an importer. Lots of tutorials available.

Comment: That is precisely what I cannot do, did you look at the example I posted? I simply cannot create 40 products with one display because I don't have suitable images for them, I only have a set of images with color shown. I am aware of the 'Enable this field...' button.

Comment: How can I create products with different colors when I only have swatches with mixed colors? Where are the tutorials you mention? have not seen anything useful so far, I want to stick with Commerce, but it does not offer the functionality that I need.

Comment: You can create a vocabulary and add terms, one term for each colour. Then you need an image of the hair in that colour, one for each Commerce product. You can then also use [Commerce Fancy Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes) if you wish. Tutorials are at https://drupalcommerce.org/videos and Youtube

Comment: Please understand that I am posting because I already went through this, I have installed Commerce Fancy Attributes and Field Extractor.

Comment: I cannot have one color for each product variation, I have only one set of images for product with a color shown, I have said this before. This paradigm of creating a product variation for each attribute is absurd, imagine Home Depot with hundreds of thousands of product creating variations for each size, color, etc. They don't do it like that and neither will I. Commerce is not mature enough, since other CMS can handle attributes very easily.

Comment: No argument there. I agree and dislike Commerce for that exact reason. But it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks for answer, there is a guy in Eastern Europe somewhere that wrote a module that MAYBE overcomes this problem http://haftmarket.pl/pl/odziez/fartuch-kelnerski-d%C5%82ugi-gala. He promised to send it to me this week, will test and post outcome here.